# code for take the link contained in the email

Tags: php, hyperlink

I wrote a code for fetching mail from the inbox in php. It is working well . But actually i need to take the link contained in the message.. I want to take the link address which are came in the message part. Can you help me for doing this..

Comment: You have 3 questions which are similar in nature (or possibly refer to the same thing). I would suggest you explain what you're trying to do so we get the full picture.

Answer (score 0):

Cant really help like this , too little information and sample .. but i would say use a regular expression to get the links out of the email .. this would vary ofcourse if the email is HTML or plain text etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you have influence on the content of the emails, make them so that the link is always on a certain line. Then walk through the email until you reach that line, then use it.

If you don't have influence on the email, definitely use a regular expression.

Comment: Thanks for replying me.The problem is i wrote the mail body tone file. I want to find the links contained in the message body from there. I can not find a solution yet. Can you please help me